# Is it possible to send HashMap as extra in adb shell am broadcast?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, adb

I'm trying to send an intent to a BroadcastReceiver that must receive a `HashMap<String, String>`

Is it possible? I already tryed many types of approaches, without success.

This is what I'm trying:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.example.INTENT_ACTION_NAME --es tag "TAG_NAME" --es data {"details":"value1"\,"type":"value2"\}' --es version "1.3"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible using `am` (at the moment).

All command line options that can be parsed by `am` can be seen in its sources: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/cmds/am/src/com/android/commands/am/Am.java.

You can try to build your own `am` with such functionality (if it's necessary enough).